# IPFS file uploading issue

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, ipfs

I just installed `IPFS` version `0.4.22` on my Mac.

When I try to upload/add a file in TERMINAL - using the following command:

`ipfs add myLogo.jpg`

I get this error:

`Error: ipfs repo needs migration`

Note: my repo version is `ipfs repo version fs-repo@7`

Additionally, when I try to run:

`ipfs daemon`

I get this error:

```
Initializing daemon...
go-ipfs version: 0.4.22-
Repo version: 7
System version: amd64/darwin
Golang version: go1.12.7
Found outdated fs-repo, migrations need to be run.
Run migrations now? [y/N]
```

So I tap on “y” to run these migrations, and I get another error message which boils down to this:

```
The migrations of fs-repo failed:
    migration failed: exit status 1
```

Here's the full error message:

```
=> Looking for suitable fs-repo-migrations binary.
=> None found, downloading.
=> Running: /var/folders/l_/793j9l1j7fx4n6pb0zd2tww40000gn/T/go-ipfs-migrate464045646/fs-repo-migrations -to 7 -y
Found fs-repo version 2 at /Users/johnSmith/.ipfs
===> Running migration 2 to 3...
applying 2-to-3 repo migration
locking repo at "/Users/johnSmith/.ipfs"
- verifying version is '2'
beginning pin transfer
- opening datastore at "/Users/johnSmith/.ipfs"
- created version 3 pinner
- loading recursive pins
ipfs migration: migration 2 to 3 failed: datastore: key not found
=> Failed: /var/folders/l_/793j9l1j7fx4n6pb0zd2tww40000gn/T/go-ipfs-migrate464045646/fs-repo-migrations -to 7 -y
The migrations of fs-repo failed:
migration failed: exit status 1
If you think this is a bug, please file an issue and include this whole log output.
https://github.com/ipfs/fs-repo-migrations
```

Obviously there's some `migrations` issue - I’ve already spent a few hours trying to troubleshoot this, but no luck.

So, what in the world is going on - and what do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: off topic, ethereum has nothing to do with ipfs :)